# two step recognition - generate mfcc through pocketsphinx in android and send it to server running sphinx/pocketsphinx?

Tags: android, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx, mfcc

I am working on large data for speech recognition and I'd like to have both speed and accuracy. I have a server currently running pocketsphinx running on large data language model. I have an android app which records audio and sends it to server for recognition, and the output is displayed on phone. But this is slow in limited internet connections since I am sending the whole audio file.

What i'd instead like to do is to use pocketsphinx on android (or part of it) to extract mfcc and send mfcc instead of the whole audio file to server.
How should I go about this? Does pocketsphinx accept MFCC as input and give recognized text as output?